# Adding a Javascript listener that triggers when an element has a certain Y position

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to add a listener that triggers a function when an element is at a certain y-position?

On click, I have an element animating up with jQuery.

During that animation, the elements y-position will reach 0 (and go past it).  When it reaches 0, I'd like to trigger another function that displays a different .

I've been trying to read about event management with anonymous event handling but have been unable to figure out how to get it working.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `step` option of animate method which is fired at each step of the animation. Here you can check for the y-position of the element and trigger the required event.

```
$(element).animate({
  height: '50%'
},
{
  step: function(now, fx) {
     //Here check the y-position of the element and then call the required function
     if($(fx.elem).offset().top == 0){
        //Code here
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - is that less taxing on the system then a listener?

Comment: @Walker - There is no such listener which will trigger when a element is moved to certain location. This is one way of doing it leveraging the animate method's step function.

Answer (score 2):

if your animation was from say 50 to -10, you could split it up into 2 animations. 50 to 0, and 0 to -10. That would give you the opportunity to call your function when the first animation completes, and wouldn't have the overhead of checking position on each step.

Comment: Ahh that's what I tried - but the way jQuery handles animations it "stops" before it keeps going.  Check out voostmedia.com/discoverly and press "search".